# Как вытащить из AMI Asterisk список peers

Tags: python, api, asterisk

Как вытащить из Asterisk AMI или AGI список peers.
Пробую так :

```
a=1
while a < 2:
    manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()
    manager.connect('100.100.100.100')
    manager.login('login', 'pass')

    ter = manager.sippeers()
    print(ter.headers)
    print(ter.response)
    time.sleep()
    a += 2
    manager.logoff()
```

но выдаёт только это

```
{'ActionID': 'HP-ProBook-4540s-00000001', 'Message': 'Peer status list will follow', 'EventList': 'start', 'Response': 'Success'}

['Response: Success\n', 'ActionID: HP-ProBook-4540s-00000001\n', 'EventList: start\n', 'Message: Peer status list will follow\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

В [описании](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_SIPpeers) AMI action "SIPpeers" указано:

> Lists SIP peers in text format with details on current status.
>   Peerlist **will follow as separate events**, followed by a final event
>   called PeerlistComplete.

Возможно в вашем случае удобней будет [подцепиться](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Allow+Manager+Access+via+HTTP) к AMI по http, там можно получить данные за один запрос, причем доступно несколько форматов для получения ответа.